# How to fix links suddenly opening in new windows in Plone?

Tags: plone

Recently I updated DNS for my organization's website to point to our new domain. After making the change, suddenly **certain links on our Plone-based website are opening in new tabs**, when they never did before.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

We are using **Plone 3.1.7.** I'm confused as to why updating the DNS affected links at all.

Tried changing the **"External links open in new windows"** setting, thinking maybe these links were being considered external. It did not make a difference.